# Custom form validation directive - 2 fields must equal 100 - AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

I have a form where selected inputs represent a percentage.  I am trying to create a validation directive to ensure the field inputs total 100.

```
app.directive("percentage", function(){
      return {
       restrict: 'A',
       require: 'ngModel',
       link: function(scope, ele, attrs, ctrl){
         if(this.val1 + this.val2 == 100){
         return true;
       }
     }
  };
});
```

Here is a plunker - http://plnkr.co/edit/qH4Q0LcUqXS3lgSOQrGT?p=preview

Not sure what is missing...

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

I am now trying this;

```
app.directive('validatePercent', function() {

  return {
   restrict: 'A',
   scope: {
     val1: "=",
     val2: "=",
     percent: "val1 + val2"
   },
   link: function (scope){
    if(scope.percent == 100){
      console.log('true');
    }
  }
};
```

But it doesn't seem to be firing.

Comment: Here is a good place to get started writing custom validators http://www.yearofmoo.com/2014/09/taming-forms-in-angularjs-1-3.html#the-validators-pipeline . I'd probably pass an expression that sums val1 and val2 into attrs of the percentage directive.

Comment: That "If" statement looks wacky.. You should probably assign the sum to a variable then do a comparison with 100 using "==="

Comment: Took a stab at making the 'if' less wacky.  Also declared the sum in scope.  Still not sure what is missing...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the directive as attribute (`restrict: 'A'`),
You can't pass scope variables the way you did (`scope: {val1: '=', ...}`), so you'd have to do something like:

```
app.directive('validatePercent', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var val1 = scope.$eval(attrs.val1);
            var val2 = scope.$eval(attrs.val2);
            console.log(val1 + val2 === 100);
            return val1 + val2 === 100;
        }
    }
});
```

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jjck702y/).